# Scope of synchronization on .class objects in the JVM

Tags: java, class, jvm, synchronization, locking

Let's say I've got the following code:

```
synchronize (Test.class) {
   ...
}
```

1. Does this mean that the `Test.class` objects is locked for every
   other program running in the same virtual machine? Or does this
   lock only affect this one program in the JVM?
2. If it affects every program: When `Test.class` is in a dependency included by two programs via different but content wise identical JARs would the lock still affect both programs?

Comment: Uhm, a JVM is one process, so what do you mean with your first question?

Comment: @fge I suppose the question might apply to multiple web apps for example.

Comment: @fge I guess your right, I didn't think about this.

Comment: you should also consider the `ClassLoader` that loads that class. If two webapps running in a single JVM synchronize on `Test.class`, they both have different instances of `Test.class` as the web apps are loaded by different class loaders.

Comment: @Arkantos that really depends, I don't think generalisations are very helpful here. Often webapps will have the same instance of a `class` - it depends on where the `class` comes from...

Comment: @BoristheSpider.. I don't get your point. Each web-app has a different class loader in a container (say tomcat), so even though `Test.class` is in the shared libs, when it's actually loaded, they both create an instance of `Test.class` unique to that class loader and that is used as lock. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: @Arkantos If the `class` is part of the container's classes - that it loads in its parent classloader, the parent of all web app classloaders, then there will only be a single instance of the `class`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider.. yup that's a possibility. Thanks for pointing that :)

Comment: @Arkantos it's not a possibility, it's a necessity.

Comment: @BoristheSpider.. yes i understand that if a class is loaded by parent class loader, then the sub class loader won't load it again, but we don't know if that's the case of OP, that's why I said that

Comment: @BoristheSpider saying parent class loader loads all classes is incorrect. Though each web app class loader has same parent class or resource loading is not delegated to parent class loader like normal java applications.

Comment: @AniketThakur it _is_, for example - [here's the Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple ClassLoaders, each one can have it's own instance of a class (or share an instance of a class) e.g. `String.class` will be shared, but `MyType.class` might be different in each "Application" assuming each application has it's own class loader.

In terms of locking, there not nothing special about the `Class` object except it is used implicitly in `static synchronised` methods.

e.g.

```
class MyType {
    static synchronized void method() { }
}
```

is much the same as

```
class MyType {
    static void method() { 
        synchronized(MyType.class) {
        }
    }
}
```

It performs the same function, though the byte code is not identical.

Answer (score -1):

Your "programs" are simply various `ClassLoader.load(programClass).main(args)` that you run multiple times. Certainly they share one classloader, one machine and are effectively different parts of the same program, one OS process. Just calling various classes `programs` changes nothing. They are still visible to each other. If one can execute methods of another, they can block each other.

Answer (score -4):

Java is an OO language which means you have Objects and they interact with each other to form a complete program. Each Object is associated with a monitor. Synchronization is essentially done over the objects which actually get a lock on the objects monitor.

Now coming to your question. When you say

```
synchronize (Test.class) {
   ...
}
```

lock is obtained over the Test.class object. Also for a fully qualified class name JVM will make sure it is loaded only once per class loader (unless it is GCed). So you will always have only one instance of `Test.class` per JVM instance (Considering class loading is done by same class loaded). By JVM instance I mean a Java process which will have it's own PID. If one thread have lock over `Test.class` no other thread can get this lock unless it is released by the holding thread (Same thread can get the lock again - Locks in Java are Reentrant nature).

If you start new java process -> new JVM instance -> new instance of `Test.class` is loaded by class loader -> It's lock can be obtained and is not dependent on any other JVM instance running.

**Note** : If Class objects are separate ( same class loaded by different class loaders for instance - like what happens in case of web apps ) then you can certainly get separate lock on each. You will not be able to cast an instance of one class to the other.

Comment: This is not true - _So you will always have only one instance of `Test.class`_. Not if you have any custom `ClassLoader` behaviour, and certainly not in a web application.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes I meant one per class loader. As far as web apps are considered classes in each web app (`/WEB-INF/classes` and `/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar`) are loader by different class loaders and will behave like different classes altogether including locking mechanism.

Comment: So correct your answer, or keep collecting downvotes. At present it is entirely incorrect.